# Plotting Time Series Data in R and Tidy

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, tidyverse, lubridate

I am trying to use `lubridate` to sort out time series data from my temperature sensors. I would ultimately like a plot that has time on the x axis and temperature on the y axis. I have been using the function `parse_date_time` to try and create a new `date` variable but all I get is `NA`.

```
temps<-temps %>% as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(date = parse_date_time(Date.Time..GMT..0500, "mdYHM"))
temps
```

[image]

Comment: @Ric S Its a bit of a large file but you can access it here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tyyp0b9rny68j4z/Temps_test.csv?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you inserted a capital `Y` when the year part only contains two digits. So you should use a small-case `y`, i.e.

```
temps %>% as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(date = parse_date_time(Date.Time..GMT..0500, "mdyHM"))
```

To produce a simple plot, here is a basic code

```
ggplot(temps) +
  aes(x = date, y = TempF) +
  geom_line()
```

For further details on the plot itself, I suggest you to have a look at `ggplot2` [documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/).

---

In my sample data it worked

```
temps <- data.frame(
  Date.Time..GMT..0500 = c("6/18/18 12:57", "6/18/18 13:57", "6/18/18 14:57"),
  var = c(1,2,3)
)
parse_date_time(temps$Date.Time..GMT..0500, "mdYHM")
# [1] "2018-06-18 12:57:00 UTC" "2018-06-18 13:57:00 UTC" "2018-06-18 14:57:00 UTC"
```

Comment: That works well but now how do you use the output date to plot it in ggplot?

Comment: @IDelToro I've added a small sample code in my answer